# How can I resize ViewPager with animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I'm beginner in Android and I have a little problem with animations yet.
I have a layout in Android with a viewpager (the pink part of the layout):
[Android ViewPager layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ycS.png)
I would like to resize the height of the viewpager with an animation when user clicking on the Skip button like this one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIJJm.png)
I've tried to set the layoutparams of the view, but I got an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error probably because you cast (LinearLayoutParams)yourViewPager.getLayoutParams();
if you want to change the height
use

```
yourViewPager.getLayoutParams().height=value;
```

if you want to animate it you can use [value animators](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html)
you can find a simple sample here also on [github](https://gist.github.com/rogerpujol/99b3e8229b7a958d0930)